# editing the source code of a pdf file

Tags: configuration

I was messing around with some files on my computer and was wondering... using the .txt form of a pdf file is it possible to edit the code within the file in order to insert a comment within the file? I tried inserting a word here and there but it kept corrupting the file...
Anyone have any idea how one might go about putting a comment into a file without totally corrupting the file?

Answer (score 1):

By “using the .txt form of a pdf file” I take it you mean editing a PDF file using a text editor. Doing so is possible, if you take into account the requirements of the PDF format; in particular, it includes a number of indexes, which need to be updated when offsets of content inside the file are changed. So really, you shouldn’t use a text editor to modify a PDF file.

Instead, you should use a PDF editor, such as [PDFedit](http://pdfedit.cz/en/index.html).